# Session seems to be working wrong in Page_PreRender

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have code in my `Page_Load` event that conditionally sets a `Session[]` variable, and then after that code that uses the value of that variable to inject `HTML` into the page. It was working fine, but I wanted to move the `HTML` generating code to run *after* controls' events, since I have a button that can also affect this variable. So I moved the second part to the `Page_PreRender` function, and it stopped working.

Here is the code that works. It even adds the label `"Good"` at the `PreRender` event, which means the `Session[]` variable is working fine:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty())
    {
        var response = openid.GetResponse();
        if (response != null)
        {
            switch (response.Status)
            {
                case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
                    Session["loginId"] = response.ClaimedIdentifier;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (Session["loginId"] != null)
    {
        Label l = new Label();
        l.Text = "Welcome " + Session["loginId"];
        loginPH.Controls.Add(l);

        Button b = new Button();
        b.Text = "Logout";
        b.Click += new EventHandler(logout_Click);
        loginPH.Controls.Add(b);
    }
    else
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Text = "Log in with Google";
        b.Click += new EventHandler(loginGoogle_Click);
        loginPH.Controls.Add(b);
    }
}

void Page_PreRender()
{
    string s;
    if (Session["loginId"] != null)
        s = "Good";
    else
        s = "NULL";
    loginPH.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = s });
}
```

Here is the code refactored to do the control adding at the `PreRender` event (I removed the testing placeholder that was there before). It should work the same, but doesn't. It always adds the login button:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty())
    {
        var response = openid.GetResponse();
        if (response != null)
        {
            switch (response.Status)
            {
                case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
                    Session["loginId"] = response.ClaimedIdentifier;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void Page_PreRender()
{
    if (Session["loginId"] != null)
    {
        Label l = new Label();
        l.Text = "Welcome " + Session["loginId"];
        loginPH.Controls.Add(l);

        Button b = new Button();
        b.Text = "Logout";
        b.Click += new EventHandler(logout_Click);
        loginPH.Controls.Add(b);
    }
    else
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Text = "Log in with Google";
        b.Click += new EventHandler(loginGoogle_Click);
        loginPH.Controls.Add(b);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem has more to do with you trying to hook up your event handlers in PreRender.
On postback the buttons won't be created until after the click event has been handled which means that the event will be ignored.

Try declaring the buttons with page scope and initialize them in Page_Init:

```
protected Button a;
protected Button b;

void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    a = new Button();
    a.Text = "Logout";
    a.Click += new EventHandler(logout_Click);

    b = new Button();
    b.Text = "Log in with Google";
    b.Click += new EventHandler(loginGoogle_Click);
}
```

Then in PreRender you can decide which button to use:

```
void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["loginId"] != null)
    {
        Label l = new Label();
        l.Text = "Welcome " + Session["loginId"];
        loginPH.Controls.Add(l);

        loginPH.Controls.Add(a);
    }
    else
    {
        loginPH.Controls.Add(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: I won't be able to test this for the next few hours, but I assumed that the event hookup of the *previous* rendering (the one the user is seeing when he clicks) is the one that sets the events fired, not the one currently rendered. Is this not so?

Comment: Dynamic controls have to be created EVERY time the page is loaded, together with any event handlers. In order for the event handlers to be called the control creation must be before postback event handling, which occurs before the rendering stage of the page lifecycle.

Comment: Oh, OK. BTW, do you now of a way to remove non-dynamic controls from the page prior to rendering?

Comment: The easiest way would be to set the Visible property to false.